# Cloud ML Engine distributed training default type for custom tf.estimator

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

This [article](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tutorials/distributed-tensorflow-mnist-cloud-datalab) suggests there are three options for distributed training

1. Data-parallel training with synchronous updates.
2. Data-parallel training with asynchronous updates.
3. Model-parallel training.

The tutorial then goes on to suggest that the code that follows performs *data-parallel training with asynchronous updates on Cloud ML Engine* which behaves as "If you distribute 10,000 batches among 10 worker nodes, each node works on roughly 1,000 batches."

However, it's not clear what portion of the code actually specifies that this is using data-parallel training with asynchronous updates. Is this simply the default for ML engine if you run it in distributed training mode with a custom tf.estimator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that `tf.estimator` is currently mostly built around Data-parallel training (2).

You get Model-parallel training simply by using `with tf.device()` statements in your code.

You could try to use [SyncReplicasOptimizer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/sync_replicas_optimizer.py#L41) and probably accomplish synchronous training (1).

All of the above applies generally to `tf.estimator`; nothing is different for CloudML Engine.

Comment: Thanks! My follow up question is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989971/distributed-training-with-tf-estimator-resulting-in-more-training-steps -- I wanted to first confirm that I should expect the data-parallel training, so I'm pretty confused by the performance that I am seeing with the distributed ML Engine experiments I am running

Comment: Also, are with tf.device() statements needed to take advantage of the GPUs? I've seen conflicting documentation suggesting that this is needed, but I am observing some speedup between BASIC and BASIC_GPU, but I'm not sure if that is due to the GPU or just that the BASIC_GPU has a larger CPU as well.

Comment: If you have one gpu (like BASIC_GPU) it's not strictly necessary to specify the device (see https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu for more info). That said, performant GPU code often requires forcing some ops on a CPU. See https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#preprocessing_on_the_cpu for more info on that.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud ML Engine doesn't determine the mode of distributed training. This depends on how the user sets up training using the TensorFlow libraries. In the mnist example linked from the article, the code is using TF Learn classes specifically an Estimator is constructed in [model.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-dist-mnist-example/blob/master/trainer/model.py)

That code selects the optimizer which in this case is the AdamOptimizer which uses asynchronous updates. If you wanted to do synchronous updates you'd have to use a different optimizer such as SyncReplicasOptimizer.

For more information on how to setup synchronous training you can refer to this [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed).

Comment: Ahh I did not realize that this was determined from the optimize, thank you! Are there other factors beyond the optimizer that would control the type of distributed training? Is the optimizer also what specifies the "data-parallel"?

Comment: I have generated my own Estimator (returning tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec) and I am looking for additional information to understand how the training is being distributed. I am also using the AdamOptimizer so based on your answer I am assuming that it is data-parallel asynchronous training, but it's not clear how I could confirm the behavior if I were to choose a different estimator. I'm not seeing this optimizer-related behavior documented anywhere so that I could determine behavior on my own. Could you share any relevant links?