# Distributed Training with tf.estimator resulting in more training steps

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am experimenting with distributed training options on Cloud ML Engine and I observing some peculiar results. I have basically altered the census custom estimator example to contain a slightly different model and changed my loss function to AdamOptimizer as the only real changes. Based on this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986578/cloud-ml-engine-distributed-training-default-type-for-custom-tf-estimator), my understanding is that any distributed training should be data-parallel asynchronous training which would suggest "If you distribute 10,000 batches among 10 worker nodes, each node works on roughly 1,000 batches." In my experiment, I have ~650k training examples and I am running the following experiments for 1 epoch with a batch size of 128. Given 650k training examples and a batch size of 128, I would expect there to be ~5.1k steps in an epoch. Here is the performance that I am seeing for different `--scale-tier`'s

**NOT DISTRIBUTED**

- BASIC: 8 steps/sec, 5.1k steps, 11 minute wall time
- BASIC_GPU: 24 steps/sec, 5.1k steps, 3.5 minute wall time

**DISTRIBUTED**

- STANDARD_1: 14.5 steps/sec -- 26k steps (26k*128 = ~3.3M which is way more than the training samples actually in the data), 29 min wall time
- CUSTOM -- 5 complex_model_m workers, 2 large_model parameter servers: 27 steps/sec, 31k steps (128*31k = ~3.9M which is way more than the 650k training samples actually in the data), wall time 20 minutes

My expectation was that the data-parallel based on the article was that the distributed training would split up the batches amongst all of the workers so if I had 5 workers on ~5k batches, then each worker would perform ~1,000 batches.  However, the actual behavior that I am observing is that it seems closer to EACH of the 5 workers performing 1 epoch themselves. When training in a distributed setting, there are 6x as many steps taken in an epoch as there are training examples -- I know that the true definition of a step is each time the gradients are updated, but my understanding of data parallel training is that this would just split up the batches so there should be the same number of gradient updates -- is there any reason why this behavior would be expected? Would it make sense for there to be more train steps needed in a data-parallel asynchronous training distributed environment? Can anybody explain the behavior that I am observing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The previous answer did a good job at explaining the performance bottlenecks. Let me explain about "epochs" and how TensorFlow processes datasets.

The way that distributed training works in TensorFlow is that each worker independently iterates through the entire dataset. It is a common misconception that the training set is partitioned amongst the workers, but this is not the case.

In a typical setup with queues (see [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues)), what happens is each worker creates it's own queue. That queue gets filled with a list of all the filenames of all the training files (typically the list is shuffled and everytime the queue is exhausted, it gets repopulated and reshuffled). Each file is read in instance-by-instance, and the data is parsed, preprocessed, and then fed into another queue where the instances are shuffled and batched. Once the last instance of any file is read, the next filename is popped off the filename queue. If there are no more files to pop, an "epoch" has completed.

The important point here is that all of these queues are by default *local* -- not shared. So every worker is independently repeating the same work -- creating queues with all the files and iterating through the entire dataset. A full epoch, then, is roughly equal to the number of instances in the full dataset * the number of workers. (I'm not sure about your standard_1 result, but the result on CUSTOM means you have your master + 5 workers = 6 workers * 650K examples * (1 batch / 128 examples) = 31K steps).

FYI the use of epochs are discouraged for parameterizing distributed training because it's too confusing and there may even be issues with it in general. Just stick with max_steps.

Note that, as a consequence of TensorFlow's design, "batch size" means the batch size *of each worker*. But each worker is going to be sending updates to the parameter servers at roughly the same rate, so over a time period roughly equivalent to the time need to process one "batch", the number of updates that happen to the parameters are roughly `batch_size` * `num_workers`. This is what we call the *effective* batch size. This in turn has a few practical consequences:

1. You tend to use smaller batch_sizes, especially if you have a large number of workers, so that the *effective* batch size stays sane.
2. As you increase the number of workers, your effective batch size increase and hence you need to decrease your learning rate, at least when using "vanilla" stochastic gradient descent. Optimizers with adaptive learning rates (such as Adagrad, Adam, etc.) tend to be robust to the initial learning rates, but if you add enough workers you still may need to adjust the learning rate.

You may wonder why TensorFlow handles training data in this fashion. It's because in distributed systems, you can't rely on machines being the same speeds, or even being reliable at all. If you partition the training data into disjoint sets that go to each worker and then one or more machines are slow relative to the other or the network goes down on one, etc., your training process will see the data from the "fast"/reliable workers more frequently than the "slow"/unreliable workers. That biases the results towards those instances (or in extreme cases, ignores it all together).

Comment: Incredible answer! This would make a great blog post as it was very difficult to find this information explained on the distributed tensorflow documentation available online.  I guess my only concern here is that if I am dealing with an unbalanced data, I liked the use of epochs to ensure that I go through all of the examples of the minority classes and it seems like using max_steps there really is no guarantee (though if you take enough steps then you should sample from even the smallest minority classes).

Comment: My understanding of optimizers like Adam is that one typically uses the learnign rates "out of the box" as they have been more or less optimized. Are there any suggested heuristics for adjusting the learning rate to deal with the larger effective batch size? I recognize that experimentation/hyperparameter tuning is likely needed, but hoping to read more to get in the right ballpark

Comment: Also, you reference max_steps -- would this be the same as train_steps in the Custom Estimator census sample at this [line](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/customestimator/trainer/task.py#L201) or is this an entirely different argument?

Comment: The theory beyond stochastic gradient descent (SGD) is based on training on data taking at uniform random *with* replacement -- this is more or less what you get with TF. In practice, however, taking random samples *without* replacement can converge faster (for reasons you stated). There is some semi-recent theoretical work on SGD and sampling without replacement.

Good point about Adam (more generally, adaptive learning rates). I'll update my post to clarify that such algorithms are generally robust to choice of learning rate.

RE: max_steps, yes, train_steps is the same thing.

Comment: @rhaertel80 I can't believe that it is not clear in the documentation the queues are local and not shared (I guess it is the same with the new dataset class). I was so wrong until I read your answer. Thanks!

Comment: According to your explanation, the distributed tensorflow can only speed you up when you have a large epoch? Because each worker should iterate all files, instead of processing part of them

Comment: @FrankHu. Distributed TensorFlow still speeds work up by processing multiple examples in parallel. Note that epoch doesn't really have meaning in this context, because you have no guarantees of visiting each instance exactly once. The nearest equivalent of an epoch would be processing N instances (N = size of the original dataset), even though some may be processed more than once and some not at all. Another possible definition is when each worker was process 1/W the data (where W=number of workers).

Comment: @rhaertel80, maybe we can use tf.dataset API and use shard() method to distribute training samples?

Comment: @FrankHu. That will technically work; it didn't exist when this post was written :). That being said, if you do it and a worker goes down or one worker is slower than the rest, will result in a model skewed towards the data in the other workers. shard does not force workers to synchronize after each epoch, to my knowledge. But, you can probably used it with `SyncReplicasOptimizer`. Your throughput will be limited by the slowest worker.

Comment: @rhaertel80 Currently the practice is to scale the learning rate linearly with the batch size (see [this paper](https://research.fb.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/imagenet1kin1h5.pdf)). You say we have to decrease the LR when increasing the batch size but the current practice is different. I probably understand why we need to decrease the LR (since we have more updates / unit of time coming to the parameter server) but then it would increase the convergence time? Can you elaborate on this please?

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of severs:

- Workers: which perform the graph computation
- Parameters servers: which store the parameters, so all the workers can share and update the parameters

You can have a bottle neck in the parameters servers. If the model is very big and you have few parameters servers you need more communication between the workers and the parameters server. For example, if you have 2 parameters servers you will have half of the parameters of the model in one server and the other half in the other. If you have a lot of workers they will have to get and send a lot of parameters to different workers, and the workers will have a big lag. If you increase the number of parameters servers the lag will be reduced because there is less communication between each parameter server and the workers.

As your batch size is 128 (quite big) and you can perform 8 steps per second only in the CPU I think your model is so fast that it takes more time to share the parameters of the server than running one iteration. So you could also try to increase the batch size.

Comment: I appreciate the response. While I think I follow most of what you are saying - I'm still not entirely sure on why this would result in more train steps than train examples. Are you trying to suggest that because there is a bottleneck in the communication with the parameter server each batch size is resulting in multiple updates?  The issue I am trying ot understand is why 1 epoch results in 5.1k training steps on CPU/GPU, but the distributed setting is resulting in 30k+ steps on the same single epoch.

Comment: I didn't understand you well. My response has nothing to do with that. It should be the same number of steps regardless of distributed or single machine. What session are you using? is it `MonitoredTrainingSession`? How are you counting the steps? are you using the global_step `tensorflow.python.training_util.get_or_create_global_step()`? Are you using queues or feeding the samples in `session.run`?

Comment: I am following the custom estimator sample that can be found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/customestimator/trainer/model.py#L193) -- I am using tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step() and passing this to the train_op just as the example does.  I am running an experiment ie. learn_runner.run() and the input data is generated using tf.train.batch.  Do you see anything in that sample that would be causing problems? I believe the experiment function uses a monitored training session by default

Comment: Are you setting `max_steps` when you call `train`?  If you set this paramater it should do more than those steps, if you set `steps` it could load any previous model saved in the log dir and do that amount of steps. Don't use the same log dir for all your tests and set up the `max_steps`. It should do more than those steps.

Comment: I am using num_epochs = 1 as opposed to max_steps. It seems like each worker is performing 1 full epoch, does that seem like what you would expect? I guess that it would work to just set max_steps, but it's not clear to my why num_epochs wouldn't have the same behavior?

Comment: You are right, it seems each worker is doing a full epoch. I guess you are not using queues to feed the data but you are using placeholders. If you use placeholders probably the workers have the same code to read and feed data, it means each worker read the whole data. If you use queues these are shared among workers and two workers doesn't use the same data in run (as it would happen with placeholders).  More about queues: http://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues
The code I usually use to train (see the datasets classes): http://github.com/jorgemf/tensorport-template