# Distributed TensorFlow Using Cloud ML - Training

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to run a distributed TF job using Cloud ML.

I tested the code locally (using gcloud ml local command). Here are some specifications:

```
n_epochs = 20
noofsamples = 55000
batch_size = 100
num_batches = noofsamples/batch_size = 550
```

Using the following specifications, training steps = n_epochs * num_batches = 11000, which is correct.

But, if I execute the same job in Cloud ML using 2 worker nodes and 1 parameter server, it seems like full training is done on each machine

training steps = 3 machines n_epochs * num_batches = 33000

This shouldn't be the case.

Did any of you encounter this problem?

I would appreciate your help!

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distributed Training with tf.estimator resulting in more training steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989971/distributed-training-with-tf-estimator-resulting-in-more-training-steps)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45994422/1399222

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is yet not clear the advantages of distributed training. You also suggested to use max_steps instead of epoch. But defining max_steps as a static value is not the same as noofsamples/batch_size. When using max_steps, we can't be really sure if all the training samples are seen atleast once.

Comment: If you can use a single machine for training (fits in RAM, finishes in a reasonable amount of time), you should probably do that. But I'm assuming you need faster training or more RAM than you get on a single machine. Robust distributed training comes with some tradeoffs, one of those being that it is difficult to guarantee instances are seen exactly N times (imagine a single machine goes down and has to restart, do you want to undo all of the learning for that epoch? what if some machines are slower than others -- do you want to waste time waiting for them to catch up?)

Comment: Created an answer based on rhaertel80's comments.