# How to guarantee each worker read unduplicated data in ps-worker distribution?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing, distributed

I am trying TensorFlow distribution, as per doc here https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed , we are using data parallelism. I have setup ps-worker scripts, it up and running as expected.
but one query please help:

how to guarantee each worker read different piece of data from the mounted storage?
e.g:

I have data:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 in my storage

and two workers: worker1 and worker2

I was assuming that worker1 will read data: 1,2,5,7,9 and worker2 read 3,4,6,8,10 because of data parallelism. 
is there any related code implement this kind of magic in TensorFlow, if no, how to guarantee each worker read different piece of data from the mounted storage?

Thanks,
Allen Zhang

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that there is not built-in support for splitting the data in the current "core" tensorflow. See the top answer to this question for more details and rationale - [Distributed Training with tf.estimator resulting in more training steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989971/distributed-training-with-tf-estimator-resulting-in-more-training-steps).

Having said this, there is a new cleaner abstraction under heavy development at the moment based on a DistributionStrategy concept. In this module, there is a way to distribute the dataset- https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distribute/DistributionStrategy#distribute_dataset. However, this module is fairly rough and many parts of it are not yet implemented. I would not advice using it at the moment, unless you feel very adventurous.